# What exactly is Buddhism? Where does it help me? How can I start?

Tags: teaching, daily-life

I just discovered this website and it seems really interesting! 
But now I ask myself: "What exactly is this? What exactly is Buddhism? How can it help me? Where does it help me?" etc.

I really want to start with it (if it really helps me in everyday life), but I don't know how :(. Can anyone explain it to me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might be interested in the [resources page](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) the community has compiled for new comers.

Answer (score 3):

The exact nature of Buddhism is it exists to diagnose the suffering & problems that exist in human life for the sole purpose of overcoming & being free from suffering & problems in human life.

The Buddha said: "*I teach about two things: suffering & freedom from suffering*".

Whatever problems people have, be they related to work, finance, relationships, life skills, grief, suffering, discontent, existentialism, etc, Buddhism generally has an answer.

In short, Buddhism exists to bring human happiness, peace & freedom.

Comment: Oh wow! How can I learn it?

Comment: Ask questions about matters that are relevant to your life or, otherwise, read, study & meditate.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do a retreat at a monastery or other practice centre. Practicing in a sangha (a Buddhist community) is a fundamental part of Buddhism, and you will have the opportunity to meet a teacher and put your questions to him (or her).